# Getting SSL error while opening untrusted SSL link in XWalkView (CrossWalk)

Tags: android, android-browser, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

I'm using crosswalk as an alternative to webview in android for an application that has builtin mini browser and require lots of web navigation.

**Problem:**

Now whenever I try to navigate to a SSL based a dialog pops up saying **SSL Certificate Error Alert** and then stuck after that.

**My Gradle**

```
dependencies {
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

 //noinspection GradleCompatible
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
 implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
 implementation 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta:18.48.477.13'

 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
 core:3.0.2' 
}
```

**My Code:**

```
XWalkView xWalkView = findViewById(R.id.xwv_browser);
    xWalkView.setUserAgentString("Browser/1.0 Android");
    xWalkView.load(WEB_URL, null);
```

Any help, code, concept would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share your complete project

Comment: I follow this link,
https://progur.com/2017/01/how-to-create-a-browser-app-for-android-with-crosswalk.html